# Tool to monitor home network traffic & stats?

Tags: network, mac-appstore, monitoring, snmp

I have a home network with several users, using both LAN & Wifi. I have a Billion 7800N router which is also my ADSl2 modem.

Is there a tool or something I can use that monitors all traffic going through the router, including capturing packets? Some features im looking for is broadband usage per user/ip, packet inspection (not required but handy) and other general network stats.

I was looking at Netuse network monitor from AppStore as it also uses the SNMP data on the router, but with no trial version im not willing to buy just yet.

Thanks

Comment: We're probably not the right site to know if SNMP support for your router would capture that level of detail, but NetUse works well with receiving SNMP so think of it as a data logger. It won't do the analysis but it will help you log and capture whatever data the networking equipment is reporting.

Comment: I can’t find much info about your modem/router. By any chance, can it copy all its traffic to one of its port?

Answer (score 2):

You could put a hub on the outgoing port (ensuring all packets are visible) and hook a Mac up along with the modem and router WAN connection.

Your mac could then run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to perform deep packet inspection and analysis on all the traffic for as long as you care to collect the statistics.

Comment: If the router also doubles as an ADSL2 modem, I’m guessing its outgoing port is a phone line.

Comment: Now you're talking big bucks and custom hardware to harvest and decode ADSL. In your case, the best you could do is sniff the traffic before it leaves the local network using Wireshark. Again, to get all the traffic this way, you'll need either a high end switch or a hub. You might have to make do with the SNMP traps from the hardware router. Sorry I missed that tidbit in your post about it being the ADSL modem.